# Convert particular timezone to UTC timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone

For example my local time_zone is `Canada` and i am getting date in `Chennai` timezone. How can I convert the `Chennai timezone to UTC`?

Answer (score 0):

#### Using server time

You can call [ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#utc](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/utc) on the result.

Example:

```
Time.zone.now.utc
```

Keep in mind that `.now` is using the server time zone when `config.time_zone` is set.

#### When you receive a time

If you are getting the datetime in Chennai timezone it will probably look like this: `2019-11-26T12:20:00.655+05:30`

To convert it in different time zone, use:

```
time = Time.parse("2019-11-26T12:20:00.655+05:30")
pacific_time = time.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")

# and then UTC if you want
pacific_time.utc
```

Comment: I have tried this. But it was converting from my local timezone to UTC. Actually i need to convert from chennai timezone to UTC not from my local timezone.

Comment: Ah, I see. Just a clarification before I edit, you're receiving this from sowewhere and parse it? Or it is set in the `config.time_zone` ? What does `Time.zone` returns?

Comment: Yes, I am receiving the date from somewhere in channai timezone.

Comment: @Priyanga Does this help now?

Comment: You are saying that first I want to change the time to my local timezone and then change to UTC right?

Comment: @Priyanga no, what he wants to say is to parse the time and change it to whatever you want the timezone to be, by specifying ```time.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")```, in your case, simply add ```.utc``` to the variable storing the time, which will give you time in utc

Comment: No, I gave you an example how to switch to any timezone. You can call `utc` wherever you want, id est, you can directly go from Chennai timezone to UTC. @Priyanga let me know if my answer helped.

Comment: Yeah, I got an idea from your answer. Thanks @radubogdan

Comment: I had tried it by setting Time.zone to the chennai timezone before i am going to convert it.

Comment: @Priyanga When you get the time, it already has the timezone, see `+05:30`. If you don't have that, yes, assume is Chennai and set the server timezone to it.